# How to create an upload (large, ie ~400MB) bytestream service in Vaadin?

Tags: vaadin

In an earlier post from a few minutes ago, I asked a "general" question regarding creating general webservices in vaadin: [How can one create webservices in Vaadin 12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54011180/how-can-one-create-webservices-in-vaadin-12)

However, one specific unique case that I mainly need to support is the uploading via https of large (eg ~400MB) bytestream objects that would presumably be sent to Vaadin via an https "post" command (with the paylod being provided I presume in raw binary format as a bytestream.) I saw that Vaadin has built-in support for uploading files (which is essentially a post command of a bytestream, I presume?) and then I saw a reference to StreamReceiver here: https://vaadin.com/docs/v12/flow/advanced/tutorial-stream-resources.html

which seems to sound like a custom file importer, but I couldn't find any (simple & more-or-less complete) examples on how to use it. Ideally, a quick few lines of Java to show the "receiving" of the bytestream and a few quick lines (ideally in Java) which "posts" to the receivestream's url would be all that's needed to show how this manual upload of bytes can be accomplished in Vaadin. (In DropWizard & Jersey, I can find such examples reasonably easily, but I'm not sure how to gain that level of control in Vaadin.)

(Very very minor bonus: is there a size limit to the post command? eg, can a bytestream of over say ~4GB be sent and received?)

Answer (score 0):

In Vaadin the Upload API is optimised for streaming into File (unlike handling the stream as in Servlet and JAX-RS API). One way is to first stream to a temp file and then when the file is fully on the server side, handle the data from temp file.

Alternatively you can use [Flow Viritin add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/flow-viritin) and a helper class UploadFileHandler, which give you and API where you read the contents from InputStream, in same way as with Servlet API. See a usage example is in [this test](https://github.com/viritin/flow-viritin/blob/master/src/test/java/org/vaadin/firitin/UploadFileHandlerExample.java).

This isn't a first time this is asked and I actually have a more verbose blog draft about this subject. I'll add a link to that once I get that published.

Comment: On the server side, either the "Upload to file" or the "Flow add-on"  is an acceptable solution for now (with the latter being better since I don't need to store into a temp file). *HOWEVER*: my understanding is that the "test" code linked above creates a real "UploadFileHandler" which is some sort of GUI? But, how would one programmatically post to this "uploadfilehandle" (ie how can one treat it as a webservice)? (A sample **client** Java code doing a post to the corresponding Vaadin uploadfilehandler **server** url would probably answer all questions in one shot, if possible....)

Comment: Yes, in example user chooses a file to upload and app just counts bytes in the file. If you are sending file/input to your web app from another Java web app, then it makes no sense to do that through Vaadin UI at all. Just use plain servlet API, JAX-RS or similar, that exposes the "url where to post". It can still be in the same web app as the Vaadin UI, just through a different servlet.

If the "Java client" also happens to be in the same server, it probably makes no sense at all to use HTTP to move bytes from one place to another, but just some direct Java API.

Comment: ok, got it. I'll try the suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54011180/how-can-one-create-webservices-in-vaadin-12 @mstahv

Comment: here's the mentioned [blogpost](https://vaadin.com/blog/uploads-and-downloads-inputs-and-outputs)  :)